Use one textarea to update multiple variables
I have a webpage containing a form where for each question, the user enters a numerical response and some additional comments. The comments are currently inputted in an input type="text", but to allow for more space, I want to open a dialog with a larger textarea when the input box is clicked.
I would like to create one dialog popup box containing the textarea, which is bound using ngModel to a variable depending on which comment input box is clicked. A JS implementation would also work though.
This is what I have so far:
form-page.component.html
  <br><br>
                        <p-card class="p-fluid">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="title">
                                <span style="color:#00a499;">Maximum Demand (MVA)</span>
                            </ng-template>
                            <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                                <div class="formgrid grid">
                                    <div class="field col">
                                        <label for="remarks_max_demand">Remarks</label>
                                        <input #remarks_max_demand="ngModel" type="text" pInputText
                                            id="remarks_max_demand"
                                            [(ngModel)]="currentRemark"
                                            (click)="openRemarksDialog();setRemark(data.generalData.max_demand.remarks_max_demand)" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-card>

                        <br><br>
                        <p-card class="p-fluid">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="title">
                                <span style="color:#00a499;">Total Installed Capacity (MVA)</span>
                            </ng-template>
                            <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                                <div class="formgrid grid">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <h4 style="text-align: left;">Grid</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field col">
                                        <label for="remarks_TIC_grid">Remarks</label>
                                        <input type="text" pInputText id="remarks_TIC_grid" [(ngModel)]="data.generalData.total_installed_capacity.remarks_TIC_grid"
                                        (click)="openRemarksDialog();setRemark(data.generalData.total_installed_capacity.remarks_TIC_grid)"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

<p-dialog 
    [(visible)]="visible" 
    [style]="{ width: '600px' }" 
    header="Remarks" 
    [modal]="true" 
    styleClass="p-fluid">

    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="remarks_input">Please type any remarks.</label>
            <textarea 
                id="remarks_input"
                rows="10"
                cols="30" 
                pInputTextarea 
                [(ngModel)]="currentRemark"
                >
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
    <p-button 
        label="Continue" 
        icon="pi pi-arrow-right" 
        [text]="true" 
        (onClick)="hideRemarksDialog()" />
    </ng-template>
</p-dialog>

form-page.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { EvaluationService } from './service/data';
import { Dropdown } from 'src/app/models/dropdown.model';
import { DropdownService } from 'src/app/services/dropdown.service';
import { FilterInput, PagedResultDto } from 'src/app/models/custom.model';
import { DefinitionLibrary } from 'src/app/models/definition-library.model';
import { DefinitionLibraryService } from 'src/app/services/definition-library.service';
import { TableLazyLoadEvent } from 'primeng/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-page',
  templateUrl: './form-page.component.html',
  styleUrl: './form-page.component.scss'
})
export class FormPageComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  currentRemark!: any

  constructor(public messageService: MessageService, public evaluationService: EvaluationService, private dropdownService: DropdownService, private definitionLibraryService: DefinitionLibraryService, private router: Router) { };

    openRemarksDialog() {
    this.visible = true;

  }

  setRemark(data?: any){
    this.currentRemark = data;
  }

  getRemark(){
    return this.currentRemark;
  }

  hideRemarksDialog() {
    this.visible = false;
  }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getOpuDropdown();
    this.data = this.evaluationService.getEvaluationData()
  }
}

The above works for the first remarks box (remarks_max_demand), but not for the others. How can I get it to work for multiple boxes/variables?
Thank you!

Seems you are updating an entry from multiple entries. My advice is you shouldn't use the [(ngModel)]` that shares the same variable. Instead, you need to update the respective entry based on the selected row (by index). Would be great if you could create a demo in StackBlitz. Thanks.

@YongShun Thanks, originally my variables weren't in array form. I put it into an array, which allowed me to access and modify via index. I guess I could do a similar thing with the original object by using the object path as a parameter.
I put your comment into ChatGPT to understand your comment's context better.
Again, thanks! Solved!

To fix this issue, you need to pass the specific remark associated with each input field into the dialog and bind the currentRemark to that specific field dynamically. Instead of directly modifying the model in each input field's click event, you can refactor the logic to identify the field being clicked and bind the correct remark.
Solution:
Modify the openRemarksDialog function to accept the specific remark value.
Ensure that currentRemark is set to the specific remark for the field clicked.
Here's the updated code:
form-page.component.html
<p-card class="p-fluid">
    <ng-template pTemplate="title">
        <span style="color:#00a499;">Maximum Demand (MVA)</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
        <div class="formgrid grid">
            <div class="field col">
                <label for="remarks_max_demand">Remarks</label>
                <input #remarks_max_demand="ngModel" type="text" pInputText
                    id="remarks_max_demand"
                    [ngModel]="data.generalData.max_demand.remarks_max_demand"
                    (click)="openRemarksDialog(data.generalData.max_demand.remarks_max_demand, 'remarks_max_demand')" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-card>

<br><br>

<p-card class="p-fluid">
    <ng-template pTemplate="title">
        <span style="color:#00a499;">Total Installed Capacity (MVA)</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
        <div class="formgrid grid">
            <div class="field col">
                <label for="remarks_TIC_grid">Remarks</label>
                <input type="text" pInputText id="remarks_TIC_grid" 
                    [ngModel]="data.generalData.total_installed_capacity.remarks_TIC_grid"
                    (click)="openRemarksDialog(data.generalData.total_installed_capacity.remarks_TIC_grid, 'remarks_TIC_grid')" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-card>

<p-dialog [(visible)]="visible" [style]="{ width: '600px' }" header="Remarks" [modal]="true" styleClass="p-fluid">
    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="remarks_input">Please type any remarks.</label>
            <textarea id="remarks_input" rows="10" cols="30" pInputTextarea [(ngModel)]="currentRemark"></textarea>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
        <p-button label="Continue" icon="pi pi-arrow-right" [text]="true" (onClick)="saveRemark();hideRemarksDialog()" />
    </ng-template>
</p-dialog>

form-page.component.ts
export class FormPageComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  currentRemark!: string;
  currentField!: string;
  visible = false;

  constructor(
    public messageService: MessageService,
    public evaluationService: EvaluationService,
    private dropdownService: DropdownService,
    private definitionLibraryService: DefinitionLibraryService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  openRemarksDialog(remark: string, field: string) {
    this.currentRemark = remark;
    this.currentField = field;
    this.visible = true;
  }

  saveRemark() {
    // Save the current remark to the corresponding field
    if (this.currentField === 'remarks_max_demand') {
      this.data.generalData.max_demand.remarks_max_demand = this.currentRemark;
    } else if (this.currentField === 'remarks_TIC_grid') {
      this.data.generalData.total_installed_capacity.remarks_TIC_grid = this.currentRemark;
    }
    // Add more fields as needed
  }

  hideRemarksDialog() {
    this.visible = false;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getOpuDropdown();
    this.data = this.evaluationService.getEvaluationData();
  }
}

